# npm run build does not work - no build generated, script stops without printing anything

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flask, npm-run

My problem is pretty much described with this image:

[image]

After the 'tsc' line, it all stops executing, and my build is not generated. I recently added TypeScript and Cypress to my project before this issue occured.

I tried finding anyone that had the same problem here and over the internet, but to no avail. I also try to find some support from the creators, I hope they can help me find a solution with which I can get back to here.

My guess would be to search for the problem in the config files here: https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/tree/reactify/flack

Comment: can you share the package.json in the ...project2/flack path,
because in the git repo the path is flack/flack

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you ask for. I have only this package.json file, which is in the directory I linked. 

If the problem is that you cannot access it for some reason, than the file in question is here: https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/blob/reactify/flack/package.json

If you wanted something else, please give me more information :)

Comment: `create-react-app` officially supports `TypeScript`- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/, so unless you did something custom there things just should work... If you didn't "eject" it I'd try to `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install` again, see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I tried it now, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I guess I found something that can probably be called as a solution. In my package.json file, I had this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    // ...other stuff
  },
```

Replacing "tsc" here with "react-scripts build" seems to solve the issue. I have a build output generated now, while my typescript files still work and compile to js files. I am not sure how a "tsc" build should have worked and why it didn't, but if it's gonna work out like I'm fine with it. Thx for your suggestions though.